# C# Thread for write file to harddisk with ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, kinect, filestream

I use the kinect v2 stream to show color image and body image.
Now i want to save color image but if i add the code in the main thread i don't show nothing because write 30 files per second on the hard disk.
So i have think to use Thread, in particular ThreadPool but i have exception with frame:

```
ColorCameraSettings 'colorFrame.ColorCameraSettings' ha generato un'eccezione di tipo 'System.ObjectDisposedException'  Microsoft.Kinect.ColorCameraSettings {System.ObjectDisposedException}
```

This is my code:

```
private void Reader_MultiSourceFrameArrived(object sender, MultiSourceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var reference = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame();
        this.StatusText = "NO BODY";

        frameCount++;
        //Console.WriteLine(frameCount);
        bool dataReceived = false;
        //sw.WriteLine("frame nuovo");
        using (ColorFrame frame = reference.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null)
            {

                //image.Source = ToBitmap(frame);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(writeColorImage, frame);


            }
        }..............
```

and to write :

```
 private void writeColorImage(Object frame)
    {
        ColorFrame colorFrame = (ColorFrame)frame;
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ToBitmap(colorFrame)));
        using (var filestream = new FileStream(filelocation + "image" + frameCount + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
            encoder.Save(filestream);
    }
    private BitmapSource ToBitmap(ColorFrame frame)
    {
        int width = frame.FrameDescription.Width;
        int height = frame.FrameDescription.Height;
        PixelFormat format = PixelFormats.Bgr32;

        byte[] pixels = new byte[width * height * ((PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8)];

        if (frame.RawColorImageFormat == ColorImageFormat.Bgra)
        {
            frame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(pixels);
        }
        else
        {
            frame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(pixels, ColorImageFormat.Bgra);
        }

        int stride = width * format.BitsPerPixel / 8;

        return BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, format, null, pixels, stride);
    }
```

how can write this image on harddisk?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The using statement is calling Dispose on your frame variable; however, your thread that is running the save to disk is still using a reference to it. That's why you're getting the exception. Change this code:

```
    using (ColorFrame frame = reference.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            //image.Source = ToBitmap(frame);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(writeColorImage, frame);
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
    var frame = reference.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame();
    if (frame != null)
    {
        //image.Source = ToBitmap(frame);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(writeColorImage, frame);
    }
```

and then call Dispose() on frame in writeColorImage; change the method like this:

```
    private void writeColorImage(Object frame)
    {
        var colorFrame = (ColorFrame) frame;
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ToBitmap(colorFrame)));
        using (var filestream = new FileStream(filelocation + "image" + frameCount + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Save(filestream);
        }
        colorFrame.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: an error occured with frame.Dispose, Object don't have this method

Comment: @luca sorry, should have been colorFrame, I edited it.

Comment: Variables `frame` and `colorFrame` are references to the same object. When `Dispose` is called on any reference to the object the object is disposed (for all references to the same object). So there is no need to dispose `frame` if the object was disposed via `colorFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

You are disposing the frame just after starting your job on the thread pool. You should dispose it at the end of the job.

Remove the using in your event handler `Reader_MultiSourceFrameArrived`, then :

```
 private void writeColorImage(Object frame)
    {
        using (ColorFrame colorFrame = (ColorFrame)frame)
        {
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ToBitmap(colorFrame)));
            using (var filestream = new FileStream(filelocation + "image" + frameCount + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
                encoder.Save(filestream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any guidelines around the using statement if you're using it against an object that is created outside the using statement? I've never seen it used like that before, always used when the object being disposed by leaving the scope of the using statement is created in the using statement. To be honest, I didn't know it was possible to do it like you've done in the sample code, but I'm not sure I like it! :)

Comment: My testing indicates that C# doesn't seem to have a problem disposing of an externally created object passed into a `using` block. MSDN states, "You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged resources." In this case I think, since the alternative is no "using" block at all, this might be an exception to the rule. Better to have a "using" than not, maybe.

Comment: It's better to have the using as soon as possible. Here you can't do otherwise (you could use async but in the end the result is the same). That's fine because your task will start (no code between Acquire and QueueUserWorkItem) and the first line of the task is a `using`. Even if something goes wrong before, the GC/Finalizer will handle it. If you don't like using keyword you can add a try...finally with explicit `Dispose`.

Comment: and how can and when dispose the original frame?

Comment: @luca Calling IDisposable.Dispose or with the `using` keyword and when you no longer use it. For more information : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx